# Target with space symbol

Tags: makefile, target

I'm write the following make for experiment:

```
some_target fmake: foo.o
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).c foo.c
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET2) $(TARGET2).c
clean:
    rm -f fmake test_second
CC=$(VAR2)
VAR2=gcc
TARGET=fmake
TARGET2=test_second
```

In this case recipes of default target are always execution. But if we swap `some_target` with `fmake` the recipes will executed such as we have `fmake: foo.o` as target and prerequisites. But I'm expected that `make` check the both `some_target` and fmake. Since there is no `some_target` in `Makefile`'s directory we have that recipes are always execution. So, question is:

Is it true that

```
some_target fmake: foo.o
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).c foo.c
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET2) $(TARGET2).c
```

equivalent to

```
some_target: foo.o
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).c foo.c
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET2) $(TARGET2).c
fmake: foo.o
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).c foo.c
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET2) $(TARGET2).c
```

?

Comment: You expected wrong; the first target is the default target.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your last edit is true. The first form is identical in every way to the second form (when make sees the first form, it actually stores it internally as if you had written the second form)